# Is it possible to create a sitemap by crawling through someone's site?

Tags: javascript, python, web

For example, I want to find out what subdomains, etc. are on a website, but there's no navigation. Can I somehow crawl the site and create a sitemap? E.g., could this be done with www.google.com to find out that there is images.google.com, drive.google.com, etc.?

Also, sorry for not tagging this very well, not sure exactly how to tag it because I'm not sure where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.  Checkout the open source crawlers linked in the following article.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler